# How to create sub tables in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I want to create a table for experiments results that are save in excel sheet. I want a main table that each row represents an experiment (with the columns: Test Name, Date, Conductors, Description) and sub tables with each experiment results. I want to connect them so when I choose a row from the main table I will see the sub table with the experiment results. Is there a way to do this in SSIS?

I tries looking up how to create a parent child connection but I didn't find something that does exactly what I'm looking for

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Off the top of my head, SSIS is not going to be a great choice for what you're describing - unless you enjoy coding in .NET and the associated Office (MS or OpenOffice) libraries